# Equivalent to an Alias in AWS to use with other DNS providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to use my custom domain. I created an API Gateway with AWS and I created a custom domain name. If I had the Route53 setup I could create a new record like this:

[image]

(the Alias target above is the one created in the Custom Domain Name)

Now because I'm using a different DNS provider, I don't know what to type on the new record. This is how it looks for me:

[image]

If I put the URL there it doesn't accept it, so what is the equivalent of selecting Alias in the route53? What do I write in `IPv4 address`?

Thanks

Comment: You can use CNAME.

Comment: and for the actual value? @jingx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jingx for the hint, so in `Custom Domain Name` under API Gateway domain name, copy the value which is the URL linking the domain name to the API endpoint and on the DNS provider choose `CNAME` and that value.